# Add String to variable

Tags: swift

I have a variable `let name = ["Pete"]` and I want to add a second name to it.

Comment: You're creating an `array`. Do you want to add an element to your `array`? Or, are you trying to create a `string` and add another `string` to the end of it? You need to create your variable with `var` rather than `let` if you plan to change its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` is an array, to add another element to it you can use `append`. You'll need to make `name` variable though:

```
// Note - `name` is declared as `var` instead of `let`
var name = ["Pete"]
name.append("AnotherName") 
println(name) // ["Pete", "AnotherName"]
```

(If you're unfamiliar with Arrays I would recommend you take a look at [The Swift Programming Language: Collection Types.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105))

The naming of your variable suggests you didn't intend it to be an array though. In the case you just wanted a `String`, you could do:

```
var name = "Pete"
name += " SecondName"
println(name) // Pete SecondName
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does this also works if `var name = []`? So if `name` empty?

Comment: It will, but you'll need to declare `name` like: `var name = [String]()` or `var name: [String] = []`; otherwise `name` will be of type `NSArray`.